# Android cannot create directory

Tags: java, android, file, mkdir

I cannot create directory, I have all the permissions and this in my Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

In MainActivity onCreate, checks permission, if it has it should create a directory but it always returns a false:

```
if (!checkPermission()) requestPermission();
    else {
        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                File.separator + "receipts");
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            boolean bool = folder.mkdirs();
            System.out.println(bool);
        }
    }
```

Any clue or hint to why? Thanks

Comment: You cannot create directories off of the external storage root on Android 11 and higher using filesystem APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, with the security updates brought by Android 11 and up, as @CommonsWare said, you simply can't write directories on external storage (sdcard).

Straight from the [docs:](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage)

> Access to directories
>
> **You can no longer** use the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE intent action to
> request **access to the following directories:**
>
> The root directory of the internal storage volume.
> The **root directory of each SD card volume that the device manufacturer considers to be reliable, regardless of whether the card
> is emulated or removable.** A reliable volume is one that an app can
> successfully access most of the time.
> The Download directory.

Additionally from the same place:

> App-specific directory on external storage Starting in Android 11, apps
> cannot create their own app-specific directory on external storage. **To
> access the directory that the system provides for your app, call
> getExternalFilesDirs().**

Your app has a system generated directory to store any information. This makes sense, of course, because at any given time the user could remove/format the sd card inside the device, and your app's data would be entirely lost.

From [more docs:](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific)

You would use this to write:

```java
//Write to a file
String filename = "myfile";
String fileContents = "Hello world!";
try (FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)) {
    fos.write(fileContents.toByteArray());
}
```

And to read a file:

```java
//To read from the file
FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(filename

);
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader =
        new InputStreamReader(fis, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)) {
    String line = reader.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        stringBuilder.append(line).append('\n');
        line = reader.readLine();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Error occurred when opening raw file for reading.
} finally {
    String contents = stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

These are both within your app's "sandbox" folder. Because of this, you do not need to declare permissions.

Answer (score -1):

> > File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
> > File.separator + "receipts");

Change to:

```
 File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "receipts");
```